# How to move tag script in template to a .js file?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I want to move tag script content in template to a .js file(e.g. in this way, I can use JSHint, whatever) and put it into template directory.

I found the document that said it can treat .js file as a static file, so I must run `python manager.py collectstatic` every time when I deploy my .js file to server(because I need debug my js code). That is very trivial.

I want to put my .js file and template file which including the .js together, so how to do it?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I want to put my js and template file together, but I don't know how to do

Comment: `<script src="{% static 'js/link/to/your/resource' %}">`

Comment: @MoreFreeze putting js file inside templates folder not recommended.

Comment: @RajaSimon but I need modify js file frequently, so I must run `collectstatic ` to copy js on the static directory every time, right?

Comment: As far I know every time you have to run `collectstatic`. So that js file copied from static folder to `static_root` directory... So that django `prodution` server will give the correct `js` file when serving website...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`--link` option in collectstatic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-option--l) to symlink your files rather than copying. That means you only need to run collectstatic again when you are adding a completely new static file, since updates to existing ones will be automatically seen via the symlink.

Answer (score 1):

I add this line in my template file (e.g. template file is path/to/foo.html):

```
<script>{% include "path/to/send_bill.js" %}</script>
```

so it include .js file and add into template .html file as origin, but I can modify my .js file separately!

I don't know is there some side effect?

@Daniel Roseman your solution is very graceful.